ubuntu 22.04 is not waking up from suspend
My computer Asus tuf gaming fa706hi cant wake from suspend any ideas?
i have tried installing the AMD integrated graphics driver,
installing a 5.x Linux kernel,
and booting many distributions off USB.
any help in allowing the system to successfully wake from suspend would be appreciated.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
